# How can a click on a SearchView affecte a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-search

I have a fragment where I display some items in a `RecyclerView`. This is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how I initilize it:

```
recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
```

Now I have created a menu in my fragment that contains a single item:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

In the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function, I'm only inflating the menu layout:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bars, menu);
}
```

The problem is, as soon as I click on the [search button](https://i.ibb.co/10yKMB0/Capture.jpg) to open the edit text, I get the following warning:

> Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager set. Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument.

How can a click on a `SearchView` that is not wired in any way with my `RecyclerView` affecte its LayoutManager? How can get rid of this warning?

**Edit:**

```
public class BarsFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bars, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_bars, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the fragment layout and code?

Comment: Do you set any layout manager with the recycler view?

Comment: @notihs The fragment layout is actually the layout that is already shared. Please take a look at my fragment code in my updated question.

Comment: @Md.NowshadHasan Yes, as you can see in the layout file: `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this line on your java file.

```
recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I get the exact same behavior.

Comment: Any other thoughts?

Comment: Please google search on `Cannot scroll to position a LayoutManager set. Call setLayoutManager with a non-null argument`, check some blog with stack overflow.

Comment: Tried everything I found but without any luck :(